# Fullcalendar Header Color

Tags: fullcalendar

How do I adjust the background color of the event header in Fullcalendar?

I see that I can use color or backgroundColor to change the body of the event, but I don't see a setting for the header background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple using CSS

```
.fc-widget-header{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/PaKbx/

Passing the value from the feed is not a good idea as the header has nothing in common with events. So that would have to be passed somewhere else ;server side or jquery client side parsed from another source..

Thats just good practice-

but if you want you can pass the values back with your feed using a custom field

eg

```
[{ 'myHeaderForThisCalendar': 'Blue', ...other stuff ... }]
```

And using jquery look for that id and set your header using the CSS or ATTR function.